# Pairwise table in widyr

Tags: r, igraph, pairwise

I am trying to create a pairwise table to use in a co-occurance of author graph in R. I know generally how the `pairwise_count` function works in widyr but space separated words. My data are colon-separated so I want to know how I can create a pairwise table in this instance? I have some dummy code, below.

```
    authors_titles <- data.frame(title = c("paper_a", "paper_b", "paper_c", "paper_d"),
authors = c("Smith, David; Wright, James; Hughs, Jessica; Barro, Albert",
              "Smith, David; Wright, Jessica; Wright, James",
              "Smith, Jenny; Hughs, Jessica",
              "Wright, James; Hughs, Jessica; Barro, Albert")
)

title_author_pairs <- authors_titles %>% 
  pairwise_count(authors, title, sort = TRUE, upper = FALSE)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Separate column `authors` by the semi-colon into individual author columns, reshape to long format and count.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(widyr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

authors_titles <- data.frame(title = c("paper_a", "paper_b", "paper_c", "paper_d"),
                             authors = c("Smith, David; Wright, James; Hughs, Jessica; Barro, Albert",
                                         "Smith, David; Wright, Jessica; Wright, James",
                                         "Smith, Jenny; Hughs, Jessica",
                                         "Wright, James; Hughs, Jessica; Barro, Albert")
)

authors_titles %>% 
  mutate(sep = stringr::str_count(authors, ";") + 1L) %>%
  separate(authors, sep = ";", into = sprintf("author.%d", 1:max(.$sep)), fill = "right") %>%
  select(-sep) %>%
  pivot_longer(-title, values_to = "author") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  mutate(author = trimws(author)) %>%
  pairwise_count(author, title) %>%
  drop_na
#> Warning: `distinct_()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.7.0.
#> Please use `distinct()` instead.
#> See vignette('programming') for more help
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
#> # A tibble: 18 × 3
#>    item1           item2               n
#>    <chr>           <chr>           <dbl>
#>  1 Wright, James   Smith, David        2
#>  2 Hughs, Jessica  Smith, David        1
#>  3 Barro, Albert   Smith, David        1
#>  4 Wright, Jessica Smith, David        1
#>  5 Smith, David    Wright, James       2
#>  6 Hughs, Jessica  Wright, James       2
#>  7 Barro, Albert   Wright, James       2
#>  8 Wright, Jessica Wright, James       1
#>  9 Smith, David    Hughs, Jessica      1
#> 10 Wright, James   Hughs, Jessica      2
#> 11 Barro, Albert   Hughs, Jessica      2
#> 12 Smith, Jenny    Hughs, Jessica      1
#> 13 Smith, David    Barro, Albert       1
#> 14 Wright, James   Barro, Albert       2
#> 15 Hughs, Jessica  Barro, Albert       2
#> 16 Smith, David    Wright, Jessica     1
#> 17 Wright, James   Wright, Jessica     1
#> 18 Hughs, Jessica  Smith, Jenny        1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>